# CLion EWDK MSVC Toolchain doesn't find kernel32.Lib

Tags: visual-c++, clion

Morning,

I am currently moving my whole dev environment from VS2019 to CLion and can't get the Enterprise Windows Driver Kit (WDK) build environment working. After setting up the toolchain I get the following error message:

```
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29913.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29913.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: E:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: E:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2021.3.2/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
  The C compiler

    "E:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: A:/Git/School/Driver/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2021.3.2/bin/ninja/win/ninja.exe cmTC_02d23 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_02d23.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj
    [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_02d23.exe
    FAILED: cmTC_02d23.exe 
    cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.3.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_02d23.dir --rc="E:\PROG#OLC\WIND#B-J\10\bin\1002#1AM.0\x86\rc.exe" --mt="E:\PROG#OLC\WIND#B-J\10\bin\1002#1AM.0\x86\mt.exe" --manifests  -- "E:\PROG#OLC\MICR#M1~\2019\BUIL#ZPH\VC\Tools\MSVC\1428#Y8D.299\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe" /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_02d23.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj  /out:cmTC_02d23.exe /implib:cmTC_02d23.lib /pdb:cmTC_02d23.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cmd.exe /C "cd /D A:\Git\School\Driver\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp && C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -file A:/Git/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/msbuild/applocal.ps1 -targetBinary A:/Git/School/Driver/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/cmTC_02d23.exe -installedDir A:/Git/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows-static/debug/bin -OutVariable out""
    LINK Pass 1: command "E:\PROG#OLC\MICR#M1~\2019\BUIL#ZPH\VC\Tools\MSVC\1428#Y8D.299\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_02d23.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj /out:cmTC_02d23.exe /implib:cmTC_02d23.lib /pdb:cmTC_02d23.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\cmTC_02d23.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\cmTC_02d23.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1104) with the following output:
    LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (project)
```

So my guess would be that CLion isn't able to find the correct Windows Kit that includes the missing static linked libs.

When working with VS2019 this issues is not existing as `LaunchBuildEnv.cmd` will take care of setting all paths.

Basically you just start `LaunchBuildEnv.cmd` then type `SetupVSEnv` and start VS2019 from the cmd and all paths etc. are fixed automatically.
Unfortunately this doesn't work for CLion. When pointing CLion to the `Build Tools` folder it is able to detect everything correctly but seems to no be able to get the Windows Kits from `E:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10`.

I already tried to supply CLion with `SetupBuildEnv.cmd` as the Environment File without any success.

So I wanted to ask if somebody know how I need to supply this path to CLion so it is correctly forwarded to cl.exe.

Regards Artur

Comment: I'm desperate to make CLion work for windows driver projects. So sad

Comment: @hosseinbakhtiari Hey I ended up getting it to work. Sadly this wasn't possible with the EWDK only, so the solution is to still install the normal Build Tools and then use the EWDK only for the Driver SDK (you can also just install the normal WDK), which is automatically set up with this CMake script. 
https://github.com/SergiusTheBest/FindWDK

This will then find the Driver SDK and expose new targets for your driver which can then be simply built using CMake.

Regards, Artur

Comment: @hosseinbakhtiari
Steps to get a fresh project running, this works for existing ones as well, just add the source through GLOB or each file on its own

Steps to get the driver up and running:
1. Install Build tools https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_BuildTools.exe

2. Install WDK or use EWDK

3. Create a CMake project in CLion and place the FindWDK script in it

4. Add these lines to the CMakeList https://gist.github.com/S0PEX/fd62dfa13a404f1028cb719bb7f199c1

5. You should then be able to build the project using CLion or directly with CMake

Comment: Have you tried setting an _environment_ variable `CMAKE_WINDOWS_KITS_10_DIR` to the path in the `WindowsSdkDir`? Meaning that if you're in PowerShell, try `$env:CMAKE_WINDOWS_KITS_10_DIR = $env:WindowsSdkDir`, then delete the CMake build directory and try re-configuring.